# File transfer from QT PC app to Android phone

Tags: android, qt

how can I save a file from QT application running in PC to Android phone using USB or Android emulator?

thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Necessitas, if you go into QT_src folder on your C:\ you can see that you have a lot o examples which one of them is called http, it is app that is capable of downloading files to your phone or to your pc through the network.

Hope I helped a bit. If you can't find folder just check into QT_SDK folder if you can't find it then maybe update sdk and be sure to download source files for android.